AppDbContext dotnet tenantInfo issue in Finbuckel package
using Finbuckle.MultiTenant;
using Igmite.Lighthouse.Entities;
using Igmite.Lighthouse.Models;
using Igmite.Lighthouse.Models.Common;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using System;

namespace Igmite.Lighthouse.DAL.EF
{
    public class IgmiteDbContext : MultiTenantDbContext
    {
        private new ITenantInfo TenantInfo { get; set; }

        public IgmiteDbContext(ITenantInfo tenantInfo) : base(tenantInfo)
        {
            TenantInfo = tenantInfo;
        }

        public IgmiteDbContext(ITenantInfo tenantInfo, DbContextOptions<IgmiteDbContext> options) : base(tenantInfo, options)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("tenantInfo123" + tenantInfo);
            TenantInfo = tenantInfo;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello" + TenantInfo);
            Console.WriteLine("hello" + TenantInfo.Name);
            optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Log(CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning));

            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hello1");
                if (TenantInfo != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TenantInfo.ConnectionString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("hello2");
                    // Use the connection string from tenant info to connect to the per-tenant database.
                    optionsBuilder.UseMySql(TenantInfo.ConnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(TenantInfo.ConnectionString),
                        options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()) // <-- Enable retry logic
                        .UseLazyLoadingProxies(false)
                        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                        .EnableDetailedErrors();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("hello4");
                    // Use the default connection string if tenant info is not available.
                    optionsBuilder.UseMySql(EntityConstants.SQLConnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(EntityConstants.SQLConnectionString),
                        options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()) // <-- Enable retry logic
                        .UseLazyLoadingProxies(false)
                        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                        .EnableDetailedErrors();
                }
            }
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassSectionModel>().HasKey(c => new { c.VTId, c.ClassId, c.SectionId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ModuleUnitSessionModel>().HasKey(s => new { s.ClassId, s.ModuleTypeId, s.UnitId, s.SessionId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentByVTModel>().HasKey(s => new { s.VTId, s.ClassId, s.SectionId, s.StudentId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<VTAttendanceDetailModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.VTId, a.ReportType, a.ReportingDate });
            modelBuilder.Entity<VCAttendanceDetailModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.VCId, a.ReportType, a.ReportingDate });
            modelBuilder.Entity<DsDataManagement>().HasKey(a => new { a.AcademicYearId, a.ReportDate });
            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentClassViewModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.StudentId, a.AcademicYear, a.ClassName });
            modelBuilder.Entity<VTPSectorViewModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.VTPSectorId, a.AcademicYear, a.VTPName });
            modelBuilder.Entity<SchoolVTPSectorViewModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.SchoolVTPSectorId, a.AcademicYear, a.VTPName });
            modelBuilder.Entity<VTSchoolSectorViewModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.VTSchoolSectorId, a.AcademicYear, a.VTName });
            modelBuilder.Entity<VTClassViewModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.VTClassId, a.AcademicYear, a.VTName });
            modelBuilder.Entity<VCSchoolSectorViewModel>().HasKey(a => new { a.VCSchoolSectorId, a.AcademicYear, a.VCName });
            modelBuilder.Entity<LighthouseParams>().Property(x => x.LighthouseParamId).UseMySqlIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<MessageTemplate>().Property(x => x.MessageTemplateId).UseMySqlIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<VocationalTrainer>().Ignore(t => t.VCTrainer);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        #region "Entity"

        public virtual DbSet<AcademicYear> AcademicYears { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountWorkLocation> AccountWorkLocations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LogoutHistory> LogoutHistories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountTransaction> AccountTransactions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountUserOTP> AccountUserOTPs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountUserTerm> AccountUserTerms { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CourseMaterial> CourseMaterials { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CourseModule> CourseModules { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CourseUnitSession> CourseUnitSessions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DataType> DataTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DataValue> DataValues { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<District> Districts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Employer> Employers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Vocationaltrainerdetail> Vocationaltrainerdetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet< Vocationalcoordinatordetail>  Vocationalcoordinatordetails{ get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolSectorJob> SchoolSectorJobs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<WhatsappBroadcasting> WhatsappBroadcastings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EmailBroadcasting> EmailBroadcastings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<GenericVTMapping> GenericVTMappings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserCheckInDetails> userCheckInDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTAcademicClassSection> VTAcademicClassSections { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog> ErrorLogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ForgotPasswordHistory> ForgotPasswordHistories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HeadMaster> HeadMasters { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HMIssueReporting> HMIssueReportings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HMSchoolsMap> HMSchoolMap { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<JobRole> JobRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RoleTransaction> RoleTransactions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolCategory> SchoolCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolClass> SchoolClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolVEIncharge> SchoolVEIncharges { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolVTPSector> SchoolVTPSectors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SectorJobRole> SectorJobRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SiteHeader> SiteHeaders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SiteSubHeader> SiteSubHeaders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentClassDetail> StudentClassDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentClass> StudentClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TermsCondition> TermsConditions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ToolEquipment> ToolEquipments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserAcceptance> UserAcceptances { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserOTPDetail> UserOTPDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCDailyReporting> VCDailyReportings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DRPDailyReporting> DRPDailyReportings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCIssueReporting> VCIssueReportings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCRHoliday> VCRHolidays { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCRLeave> VCRLeaves { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCRSchoolVisit> VCRSchoolVisits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DRPRIndustryExposureVisit> DRPRIndustryExposureVisits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCRIndustryExposureVisit> VCRIndustryExposureVisits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCRWorkingDayType> VCRWorkingDayTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DRPRHoliday> DRPRHolidays { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DRPRLeave> DRPRLeaves { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DRPRSchoolVisit> DRPRSchoolVisits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DRPRWorkingDayType> DRPRWorkingDayTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCSchoolSector> VCSchoolSectors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCSchoolVisit> VCSchoolVisits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCSchoolVisitReporting> VCSchoolVisitReporting { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VocationalCoordinator> VocationalCoordinators { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VocationalTrainer> VocationalTrainers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCTrainerMap> VCTrainersMap { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VocationalTrainingProvider> VocationalTrainingProviders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTClass> VTClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTClassSection> VTClassSections { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTDailyReporting> VTDailyReportings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTFieldIndustryVisitConducted> VTFieldIndustryVisitConducteds { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTFSection> VTFSections { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTFUnitSessionsTaught> VTFUnitSessionsTaughts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTFStudentAttendance> VTFStudentAttendances { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTGuestLectureConducted> VTGuestLectureConducteds { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTGStudentAttendance> VTGStudentAttendances { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTGUnitSessionsTaught> VTGUnitSessionsTaughts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTGMethodology> VTGMethodologies { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTGSection> VTGSections { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTIssueReporting> VTIssueReportings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTMonthlyTeachingPlan> VTMonthlyTeachingPlans { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTPAcademicYearsMap> VTPAcademicYearMap { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTPCoordinatorsMap> VTPCoordinatorMap { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTPMonthlyBillSubmissionStatus> VTPMonthlyBillSubmissionStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTPracticalAssessment> VTPracticalAssessments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTPSectorJobRole> VTPSectorJobRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTPSector> VTPSectors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRActivityType> VTRActivityTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRReasonOfNotConductingTheClass> VTRReasonOfNotConductingTheClasses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRAssessorInOtherSchoolForExam> VTRAssessorInOtherSchoolForExams { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRAssignmentFromVocationalDepartment> VTRAssignmentFromVocationalDepartments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRClassSectionsTaught> VTRClassSectionsTaughts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRCommunityHomeVisit> VTRCommunityHomeVisits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRHoliday> VTRHolidays { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRLeave> VTRLeaves { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<EBSEmail> EBSEmails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRObservationDay> VTRObservationDays { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTROnJobTrainingCoordination> VTROnJobTrainingCoordinations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRParentTeachersMeeting> VTRParentTeachersMeetings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRStudentAttendance> VTRStudentAttendances { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRTeachingNonVocationalSubject> VTRTeachingNonVocationalSubjects { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRTeachingVocationalEducation> VTRTeachingVocationalEducations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRTrainingOfTeacher> VTRTrainingOfTeachers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRTrainingTopic> VTRTrainingTopics { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRUnitSessionsTaught> VTRUnitSessionsTaughts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRVisitToEducationalInstitution> VTRVisitToEducationalInstitutions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRVisitToIndustry> VTRVisitToIndustries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTRWorkingDayType> VTRWorkingDayTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTSchoolSectorJobRole> VTSchoolSectorJobRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTSchoolSector> VTSchoolSectors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTStatusOfInductionInserviceTraining> VTStatusOfInductionInserviceTrainings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTStudentAssessment> VTStudentAssessments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTStudentPlacementDetail> VTStudentPlacementDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTStudentResultOtherSubject> VTStudentResultOtherSubjects { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTStudentVEResult> VTStudentVEResults { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BroadcastMessage> BroadcastMessages { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IssueMapping> IssueMapping { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IssueApprovalHistory> IssueApprovalHistories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Block> Blocks { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Cluster> Clusters { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentClassMapping> StudentClassMapping { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTReportSubmission> VTReportSubmissions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentsForExitForm> StudentsForExitForm { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentsForExitSurveyViewModel> StudentsForExitSurveyViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ExitSurveyDetails> ExitSurveyDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ExitSurveyReportModel> ExitSurveyReports { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DsDataManagement> DsDataManagement { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AcademicRollOverResponse> AcademicRollOver { get; set; }

        #endregion "Entity"

        #region "ViewModel"

        public virtual DbSet<AcademicYearViewModel> AcademicYearViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountRoleViewModel> AccountRoleViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountViewModel> AccountViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountTransactionViewModel> AccountTransactionViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountUserOTPViewModel> AccountUserOTPViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AccountUserTermViewModel> AccountUserTermViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CountryViewModel> CountryViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CourseMaterialViewModel> CourseMaterialViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CourseModuleViewModel> CourseModuleViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DataTypeViewModel> DataTypeViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DataValueViewModel> DataValueViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DistrictViewModel> DistrictViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DivisionViewModel> DivisionViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<GenericVTMappingViewModel> GenericVTMappingViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EmployerViewModel> EmployerViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet< VocationalcoordinatordetailViewModel>  VocationalcoordinatordetailViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VocationaltrainerdetailViewModel> VocationaltrainerdetailViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolSectorJobViewModel> SchoolSectorJobViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<WhatsappBroadcastingViewModel> WhatsappBroadcastingViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EmailBroadcastingModelViewModel> EmailBroadcastingModelViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VTAcademicClassSectionViewModel> VTAcademicClassSectionViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ErrorLogViewModel> ErrorLogViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ForgotPasswordHistoryViewModel> ForgotPasswordHistoryViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HeadMasterViewModel> HeadMasterViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HMIssueReportingViewModel> HMIssueReportingViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<JobRoleViewModel> JobRoleViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PhaseViewModel> PhaseViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RoleViewModel> RoleViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RoleTransactionViewModel> RoleTransactionViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolCategoryViewModel> SchoolCategoryViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolClassViewModel> SchoolClassViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolViewModel> SchoolViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolVEInchargeViewModel> SchoolVEInchargeViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchoolVTPSectorViewModel> SchoolVTPSectorViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SectionViewModel> SectionViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SectorJobRoleViewModel> SectorJobRoleViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SectorViewModel> SectorViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SiteHeaderViewModel> SiteHeaderViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SiteSubHeaderViewModel> SiteSubHeaderViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StateViewModel> StateViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentClassDetailViewModel> StudentClassDetailViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentClassViewModel> StudentClassViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TermsConditionViewModel> TermsConditionViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ToolEquipmentViewModel> ToolEquipmentViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TransactionViewModel> TransactionViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserOTPDetailViewModel> UserOTPDetailViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCDailyReportingViewModel> VCDailyReportingViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DRPDailyReportingViewModel> DRPDailyReportingViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCIssueReportingViewModel> VCIssueReportingViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCSchoolSectorViewModel> VCSchoolSectorViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VCSchoolVisitViewModel> VCSchoolVisitViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VocationalCoordinatorViewModel> VocationalCoordinatorViewModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VocationalTrainerViewModel> VocationalTrainerViewModels { get; set; }
        
        public virtual DbSet<DashboardSchoolVisitStatusModel> DashboardSchoolVisitStatusModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<DashboardIssueManagementModel> DashboardIssueManagementModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<VocationalTrainersCardModel> VocationalTrainersCardModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<JobRoleUnitCardModel> JobRoleUnitCardModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ClassCardModel> ClassCardModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentCardModel> StudentCardModels { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ComplaintRegistration> ComplaintRegistrations { get; set; }
        
        public object SchoolSectorJob { get; internal set; }
    }
}

I am using the above IgmiteAppDbContext file but here I am not able to get the tenantInfo from the tenantInfo Object suppose I am getting null value for tenantInfo.name and all but when I used the tenant info in some controller I am getting there by using Multiaccessor but here I am getting the object but not its attribute.
Why ?
I should have got the tenantInfo.Name and other details as well .
I have registered the TenantInfo in startup.cs also.
